# Python print regex in json string

Tags: python, regex, json

So, I'm using a small python script to try to simply print out every occurrence of a website 'northwest.hall.*' where the wildcard(*) is a number, in a very large json string pulled from a url.

I have this so far:
    import urllib, json, re

```
url = 'http://graphite.website.com/render/?target=stats.web.northwest.hall.*&format=json'
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
code = re.findall('northwest', data)
print code
```

This should return a list of the 30 regexpressions of northwest.hall.number in the json string being parsed, but I get the following error instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arin/Desktop/scripts/code_parser2.py", line 7, in <module>
    code = re.findall('community', data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

New to Python (sure you can tell).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you verified that the data you are pulling down looks like what you think it does before applying the regex?

Comment: When I try your URL, I get `404 - File or directory not found`.

Comment: I get `404` too so I use http://httpbin.org/headers to get some json from server http://httpbin.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
data = response.read()
```

to get json string from server.

Using

```
data = json.loads(response.read())
```

you change this string into python dictionary.

---

**EDIT:**

```
import re

data = """
stats.web.northwest.hall.01
stats.web.northwest.hall.223
stats.web.northwest.hall.31
stats.web.northwest.hall.4
"""

print re.findall(r'stats.web.northwest.hall.(\d+)', data)

['01', '223', '31', '4']
```

Comment: Awesome furas, always humbling hearing from a pro. I get back 30 instances of 'northwest'. How do I get just the numbers following the string stats.web.northwest.hall. ? Thanks again!

Comment: Do you mean something like example in my answer ?

Comment: Perfect! If you're ever in San Francisco, I want to buy you a beer. In fact, many.

Comment: San Francisco is too far for me :(  I'm from Poland in Europe ;)